# Grammaticality: appears/looks/seems the same

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. B appears/looks/seems the same as C
> 2. B appears/looks/seems TO BE the same as C
>
> My intended meaning: B seems to be identical to C, but I'm unsure of this.

I guess that 1 is simply 2 with [verb phrase ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29#Verb_phrase_ellipsis), but is 1 wrong in any way?
Somehow, it just  sounds wrong to me. Might anyone know how or why? 2 sounds fine to me though.
Also, I guess that **[the same](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/same)** here is a pronoun.

Comment: You might google up "raising verbs": *seems* is a typical *raising verb*. Here's [one good page with explanation](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/ling150/ch9.html)

Comment: Somehow, not somewhy.  This is your second offence. Third offence is a mandatory life sentence in the US.

Comment: One reason we are asking you to use normal, everyday English, and not esoteric English (*somewhy*) is because we figure you want to know everyday English. But when you use esoteric English or sayings that are all but dead (I lighted (up)/on), it gives one the impression that you would rather use these weird forms. This can give rise to doubting your sincerity and cause some here to **stop helping you**.

Comment: No, version 1 is not wrong in any way.

Comment: Both are correct in the US (though I believe the British might use "same to"), but the implication of using "to be" is to emphasize that while it *appears* the same, there is some question as to whether it actually *is* the same. This is not a clear-cut distinction, however.

Answer (score 2):

"Seems the same" means literally that they look similar
"Seems TO BE same" might imply circumstances under which they look similar but aren't actually the same.